# Stylesheets not loading in mediawiki

Tags: apache-2.2, mediawiki, css, mod-alias

I'm trying to set up an internal mediawiki site with version 1.19 on RHEL 6.2 with Apache. On loading any wiki page, Mozilla reports

> Error: The stylesheet http_and_ipaddress/mediawiki/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%2Cshared%7Cskins.vector&only=styles&skin=vector&* was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".
>   Source File: http_and_ipaddress/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page
>   Line: 0

[I'm substituting the protocol and ip to make serverfault happy]

Yet upon checking my access_log, I see 304 reponses

> Y.Y.Y.Y - - [08/Apr/2013:19:52:26 +0000] "GET /mediawiki/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%2Cshared%7Cskins.vector&only=styles&skin=vector&* HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http_and_ipaddress/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.24) Gecko/20111104 Red Hat/3.6.24-3.el6_1 Firefox/3.6.24"

My assumption is that something (other than the stylesheet) is being returned. Do I have an issue with my Aliases?

```
Alias /mediawiki/index.php           /var/www/html/mediawiki119/index.php
Alias /mediawiki/load.php            /var/www/html/mediawiki119/load.php
Alias /mediawiki/api.php             /var/www/html/mediawiki119/api.php
Alias /mediawiki/opensearch_desc.php /var/www/html/mediawiki119/opensearch_desc.php
Alias /mediawiki/skins               /var/www/html/mediawiki119/skins
Alias /mediawiki/images              /var/www/html/mediawiki119/images
Alias /mediawiki                     /var/www/html/mediawiki119/index.php

# Remove this after installing.
#Alias /mediawiki/mw-config               /var/www/mediawiki119/mw-config

<Directory /var/www/mediawiki119>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/mediawiki>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/mediawiki/images>
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: It could be interesting to know what is the content returned by the server for this request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was working, but the browser I was using (Firefox 3.6) was not loading the stylesheet. I was able to load the site properly in a different browser (and then in FF after clearing the cache)

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact same problem, with the same exact distro.  I got the rpm from the EPEL repository.  Though it appears fixed in your instance, for me the load.php entry was not being created in the conf.d/mediawiki119.conf file. It also wasn't creating the symlink from /var/www/mediawiki119/load.php to /user/share/mediawiki119/load.php.

For those who don't have a self fixing server like @benf if you fix those two things it will work.

The load.php script was a new feature that loads the skins which is probably why they forgot it in some of the configuration files.

Comment: Absolutely check the .conf file, if load.php is missing then the style sheets will not work.  Good find, @khaki54